# Concurrent Dictionary with 500k kvps (delete kvps or not)

Tags: vb.net, performance

I have a program that runs for 500k devices-under-test (DUT) (numbered from 1 to 500k; keys also numbered so). After completion of a set of 500k DUTs, the program runs for another 500k, so on and so forth. As each DUT gets tested, I create a key-value-pair (kvp) for the DUT, in a concurrent dictionary. Now, I am wondering:
1. whether after a single set of 500k DUTs has completed its testing, should I delete the concurrent dictionary of all the 500k kvps and add add the kvps again for the next set of 500k DUTs, or
2. only clear the values for all the previous 500k keys, and add the values for the corresponding new 500k DUTs against their respective keys?

Which one is better in terms of time-performance? ( I believe option#2 is better)
The host system has enough memory to keep data for 500k DUTs all throughout the lifetime of the program. Hence, I am not considering memory as constraint.

Comment: If there is a power cut after 499,999 DUTs, would you have to run the entire batch again?

Comment: I think you're micro optimizing here; unless there is a demonstrable performance problem, you're really asking about whether you should pre-fill a dictionary with half a million nulls that you will later attach objects to, versus adding half a million objects. In real terms they take similar efforts because the object must be hashed and then the lookup considers whether it exists in the dictionary or not before adding or updating but nothing is being optimized. It is the hashing that takes the time and the lookup has to be done anyway. I'd argue that prefilling is slower because it's useless

Comment: @AndrewMorton, that would be no. I don't have to run the batch again.

Comment: @CaiusJard,thanks. I guess I have to quantify it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, to think of it, nothing really. I wanted to know whether it might vary across different systems (window 7, 10, etc., different .NET versions).

Comment: The amount of time you've already spent thinking about this, asking about this and will spend investigating this will far exceeds any savings you'll make in either direction. Just create a new dictionary and load it all over again. It requires one less line of code than using a for loop to set every value of every key to null, an operation that demands half a million assignments (that, if nothing else, are pointless because there will soon be another assignment to the same key with another different value). Or even don't bother renewing the dictionary; just load it again